# How do I change the numeric to named month in the format I want for e.g 11 as in Nov

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using the following batch script

```
echo on
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%
set "_year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
set "_month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "_day=%MyDate:~6,2%"
REN "C:\Year 2020\Oct'2020\Data_Sept'2020.xlsx" "Data_%_month%'%_year%.xlsx"
```

I get the output as `Data_11'2020` whereas I want the output to be `Data_Nov'2020`

Comment: What did you find using the search facility at the top of the page? and what was the search string you used when you used it?

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%c in (12,Dec,11,Nov,10,Oct,09,Sep,08,Aug,07,Jul,06,Jun,05,May,04,Apr,03,Mar,02,Feb,01,Jan) do if not defined _month (set "_month=%%c"&goto converted) else if %%c==%_month% set "_month="
:converted
```

Note that you could also extend the list with

```
  ,9,Sep,8,Aug,7,Jul,6,Jun,5,May,4,Apr,3,Mar,2,Feb,1,Jan
```

to cater for situations where you may have a one-digit `_month`

In fact, you could use this as a general-purpose "convert-one-string-to-another" routine